# Errors in MFC dialog application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I am learning MFC Dialog Applications and as the first try I did the tutorial  [explained here](http://depts.washington.edu/cmmr/biga/chapter_tutorials/VC_Guide/CreatingDialogAppWithMFC7.pdf)

I am using visual Studio 2010 but when I run this I get errors as
`error C2664: 'DDX_Control' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'CString' to 'CWnd &'
1>\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mfc\mfc\mfcdlg.cpp(75): error C2065: 'IDC_BUTTON1' : undeclared identifier
1>\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mfc\mfc\mfcdlg.cpp(75): error C2065: 'IDC_BUTTON1' : undeclared identifier
1>\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mfc\mfc\mfcdlg.cpp(76): error C2065: 'IDC_COMBO1' : undeclared identifier
1>\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mfc\mfc\mfcdlg.cpp(76): error C2065: 'IDC_COMBO1' : undeclared identifier
1>`

I did exactly as mentioned in the note.

```
void CMFCDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_FIRSTNAME, m_strFirstName);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_LASTNAME, m_strLastName);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_TITLE, m_strTiltle);
    DDX_LBString(pDX, IDC_NAMELIST, m_strFullName);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_NAMELIST, m_NameList);
}
```

As this is my first time doing anything in MFC applications I have no idea what went wrong.Can someone please help me to understand what is wrong?

Comment: since you are new to mfc and c++ you can look on msdn more informations about the errors you find, you can see thes links  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/s5b150wd(v=vs.100).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ewcf0002(v=vs.100).aspx for more info about your errors

Comment: You should show us the declarations of variables you pass as the 3rd parameter of the DDX_ functions.

Comment: Did you rename the controls according to Table 2? If yes, change the mfcdlg.cpp loines with errors to the current IDs of controls, so you will get rid of 'undeclared identifier' errors.

Answer (score 4):

I am not very sure you followed the steps in the tutorial correctly, you should not get these errors if you had...

C2664 Error: change `DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_TITLE, m_strTiltle);` to `DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_TITLE, m_strTiltle);`

C2065 errors: The tutorial does not contain `IDC_BUTTON1` / `IDC_COMBO1`, it mentions a `IDC_ADD` button and a `IDC_TITLE` combo box.

Answer (score 3):

`m_strTitle` is a value of type `CString`, in your code `m_strTitle` is define as a control. For the rest, you maybe have rename or delete identifiers, use appropriate.